# Using Google Maps API with Lightning Web Components to retrieve Latitude and Longitude - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, google-map, google, cors

I need to get latitude and longitude results from a text input that takes an address or zipcode. I am trying to do this with Lightning Web Components either using a LWC input with loadScript or lightning-input-address that has the Google Maps API built in.

The latitude and longitude from the user input address will be passed to a SELECT statement that uses GEOLOCATION(:lat,:long) example GEOLOCATION(10,10).

Ex:

```
String units = 'mi';
List<Account> accountList = 
    [SELECT ID, Name, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude 
     FROM Account 
     WHERE DISTANCE(My_Location_Field__c, GEOLOCATION(:lat,:long), :units) < 10];
```

This is a public user inputing an address in a Salesforce Community. **Has anyone had success using loadScript before with Google Maps?**

```
connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            //loadScript(this, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly')
           //^^^ CORs issue
            loadScript(this, map)
          ]).then(() => {
              this.initMap();
          });
    } 

initMap() {
    const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
```

OR does anyone know **how to grab latitude and longitude** from lightning-input-address?

```html
<!--**HTML:** -->
<lightning-input-address
     address-label="Search Address"
     street-label="Street"
     city-label="City"
     country-label="Country"
     province-label="Province"
     postal-code-label="PostalCode"
     street="Default Street Line"
     city=""
     country=""
     province=""
     postal-code=""
     required
     field-level-help="Select Search Address"
     show-address-lookup
     onchange={handleAddressLookupChange}>
</lightning-input-address>
```

```js
//**JS:**
    handleAddressLookupChange(event) {
        console.log('address', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)));
    }
```

```
**console log output:**
address 
{street: "10930 Fair Oaks Boulevard", city: "Fair Oaks", province: "CA", country: "United States", postalCode: "95628", …}
city: "Fair Oaks"
country: "United States"
postalCode: "95628"
province: "CA"
street: "10930 Fair Oaks Boulevard"
validity: {}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

The address lookup is supported out of the box. You will be able to verify this only in the **Production** instance and not in a developer sandbox.

First, make sure in your production org you have the below settings enabled

- Type Maps in the Quick Find box and select **Maps** and **Location Settings**.
- Click **Edit**.
- Check **Enable Maps** and **Location Services** and hit **Save**.

Next just use the below code

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Address Lookup using Google Maps Places API">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning-input-address
            address-label="Billing Address"
            street-label="Street"
            city-label="City"
            country-label="Country"
            province-label="Province"
            postal-code-label="PostalCode"
            street="Default Street Line"
            city=""
            country=""
            province=""
            postal-code=""
            required
            field-level-help="Select Billing Address"
            show-address-lookup
            onchange={onchange}>
        </lightning-input-address>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

> Carefully note `show-address-lookup` attribute in there

**Update**

- Activate Data Integration Rules for GeoCode in your org as shown below

[image]

Use check for new data to sync the Geo Codes
[image]

Check more details here via docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_admin_automatically_get_geocodes_for_addresses.htm&type=5)

**Update**

Looks like your requirement is very specific and needs some apex to make a call to Google Maps API to get [coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview). The details of the API are discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview).

Comment: Hi @Mohith, the address lookup works for me however the question I need answer is how to retrieve latitude and longitude coordinates to use in a SELECT statement that uses GEOLOCATION(lat, long)

Comment: @Fawn Updated the answer! Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Mohith unfortunately no this does not help. The user can enter any address not one that matches an account. They are most likely going to enter their address and I want to return Accounts that are within a certain distance to that entered address.

Comment: Ah I see! Well you need an apex https callout to google to get this info then!